# How to use Vault generated certificates for Internal Domains in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, hashicorp-vault, aws-elb, curl

I have generated certificates for an internal domain using Hashicorp Vault. I have exported the private key, certificate body and certificate chain.

I have uploaded the certificate onto AWS Certificate Manager and am using it on a Classic Load Balancer where I am terminating the SSL at the load balancer.

To verify, when I run a curl command, I get the following error:

```
$ curl --cert yash.pem https://nginx-classic-test-1046423204.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com -v
*   Trying 3.105.157.201...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to nginx-classic-test-1046423204.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com (3.105.157.201) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* could not load PEM client certificate, LibreSSL error error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
* Closing connection 0
curl: (58) could not load PEM client certificate, LibreSSL error error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

Can anyone please suggest me the right way to test HTTPS connection for the certificate generated through Vault?